# Unable to select XElements with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to select nodes using LINQ but I cannot understand why this simple query does not work.

My xml is like this:

```
<config>
  <func_list current_app="GSCC" flag="0">
    <func id="GSCC">
      <BLOCKS>
        <BLOCK id="1" type="ACTIONS">
          <ITEMS>
            <ITEM id="1" type="UINT32" size="1" value="1" />
            <ITEM id="2" type="UINT32" size="1" value="5" />
            <ITEM id="3" type="UINT32" size="1" value="0" />
          </ITEMS>
        </BLOCK>
      </BLOCKS>
    </func>
  </func_list>
</config>
```

Now, I have an XElement (_funcNode) which points to 'func' node:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xBlocks = from el in _funcNode.Descendants("BLOCK")
                                where el.Attribute("type").Value == "ACTIONS"
                                select el;

if (!xBlocks.Any()) return false;
```

Also the xBlocks.Any() throws an System.NullReferenceException exception.
Any idea?

Comment: Select will never ever return `null`.  If you're getting a NRE then you're not using the code that you showed.

Comment: This could give you an error `el.Attribute("type").Value`

Comment: Your example works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vOmeXz

Comment: Sincerely I don't know why using the cast work. I think the NRE is raised by the WHERE clause as @csharpwinphonexaml said..but why?

Comment: Perhaps because you have a `BLOCK` element with no `type` attribute somewhere in your XML?

Comment: Damn @AndrewWhitaker you're right!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing the query to:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xBlocks = from el in _funcNode.Descendants("BLOCK")
                                where (string)el.Attribute("type") == "ACTIONS"
                                select el;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You main problem is your Query does not add up to your xml.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xBlocks = from el in _funcNode.Descendants("BLOCK")
```

What you want to use is

```
_funcNode.Descendants().Elements("BLOCK")
```

Try to do this

```
var doc = _funcNode.Descendants("BLOCK")
```

See what doc looks like.

Comment: `_funcNode.Descendants().Element(...)` will not compile. Maybe you meant `Elements`?

Comment: I did, but I removed it